# Change Message on Sony Reader to “Do not disconnect”

Tags: usb, sony

When I connect a Sony Reader to an USB port “USB connected” is shown on the Reader. When the Sony “Reader Library” software is started this message changes to “Do not disconnect”. I want to implement this in a software tool to. There seems to be no file locked. Perhaps it is done via ebookUsb.dll. Does anybody know how this is done from any programming language? I like to see an example.

Answer (score 0):

There is an [Unofficial Sony Reader SDK](http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q=%22Unofficial+Sony+Reader+SDK%22), try experimenting with that.

Comment: I saw this but still am not able to find the function that enables and disables this text.